# Writing a script file using arrays

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

Hello I'm testing my self by using a tutorial on writing linux shell scripts
ran into this issue usinng shell arrays.
the syntax is being written using vi

```
name[0]=chuck
name[1]=samson

echo "hello, ${name[0]}"
echo "hello, ${name[1]}"
```

and saved file using `:wq`. I tried to run the file using `sh svar.sh` but got

```
name[0]=chuck is not found
name[1]=samson is not found
```

However when using coding ground GNU Bash v4.4 the scripts run correctly
Why it doesn't work under this on this OS?

Comment: What is the shell? Works for me in bash. What is "this OS"?

Comment: AFAIK `sh` doesn't support arrays. Try running with `bash.svar.sh`.

Comment: In ubuntu `sh` points to `/bin/dash` not as in the rest of the world to `/bin/bash`. This was a fun little gotcha introduced by Ubuntu devs years ago which, considering the massive installed base of `bash` scripts amounted to  a prank.

Comment: @StephenBoston [`sh` is also `dash` on Debian.](https://wiki.debian.org/Shell)

Comment: Thankyou it works using ./file

Answer (score 3):

Add `#!/bin/bash` shebang.

Older Ubuntu versions had `ash` as the default shell, that didn't support arrays.

And run the script this way:

```
./svar.sh
```

Don't use `sh`, etc.

Comment: IIRC shebang is ignored when interpreter is specified while running the script. It seems OP is using `sh file` to run the script. This answer is unlikely to work unless OP uses `bash` explicitly in place of `sh` or make the script executable and run using `./file`.

Comment: OP never mentioned how they run the script.

Comment: "*I tried to run the file using `sh svar.sh` but got*". See above the error.

Comment: Ooos, didn't notice that.

Comment: Thank you it worked ./file